# Popping from NavigationStack clears screen before disappearing

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

For some reason, clearing a navigation stack gives an unintended animation when compared to dismissing regularly. It clears the screen before it actually animates away. How can you pop back to root normally without the clearing of the screen?

https://imgur.com/a/GYhtmCK

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var navigationPath: NavigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                NavigationLink(value: 0) {
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { _ in
                SubView(navigationPath: $navigationPath)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Binding var navigationPath: NavigationPath
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            Button {
                navigationPath = NavigationPath()
            } label: {
                Text("back")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see this when running on an iPhone 14 Pro simulator with iOS 16.4. The green page slides off seamlessly as the red page slides back in. Pressing the Back link (top-left) works just as well as pressing the ```Button``` on the green page. What environment are you using?

Comment: @BenzyNeez I am seeing the issue. iPhone 14 Pro on iOS 17 latest beta.

Comment: This looks like a bug for swiftui not from you.   My guess is state from parent view is handled  before checking animation of current view.  I would suggest to not use @Binding for navigation path, like putting it inside environment object.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but in my case it only happened on simulator. Could you try on a real device if it still occurs?

Comment: Yeah it still looks like that for me on a real device

Comment: @Martin Actually, I just rebuilt the app again on my phone and the animation works correctly. It looks like the bug was fixed recently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation seems to be working properly now, looks like SwifUI has patched the bug.

Answer (score 0):

`How can you pop back to root normally without the clearing of the screen?`
You could try this alternative approach, using `dismiss()` to go back, works for me.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var navigationPath: NavigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            ZStack {
                Color.red
                NavigationLink(value: 0) {
                    Text("test")
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { val in
                SubView() // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.green
            Button {
                dismiss() // <-- here
            } label: {
                Text("back")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works if you only intend to dismiss the `SubView` from inside the view itself. I think the question more aims to have a programmatic way to dismiss the view with only a reference to the navigation path.

This would be useful, for example, if we have a tab bar and we want to navigate back to the root tab when a tab bar button is pressed.

Comment: I've only answered the question as posted, I did not speculate or second guessed what the OP wanted. The OP should make it clear if the question is `...to have a programmatic way to dismiss the view with only a reference to the navigation path`